# Quiero realizar un programa que calcule el área y perímetro de los tres tipos de triángulos pero falla al compilar

Tags: c++, dev-c++, float, double, scanf

```
//Este programa calcula el área y perímetro

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    printf("En este programas podras calcular el area y perimetro del triangulo escaleno, equilatero\n");

    //Zona de variables

    float area;

    float perimetro;

    float entre=2;

    double figura1;


    float TrianguloIsoseles;

    float TrianguloEquilatero;

    float base;

    float altura;

//Eligue La figura

printf("Elige una Figura\n");

scanf("%lf" ,&figura1);

scanf("%lf" ,&TrianguloEquilatero);

scanf("%lf" ,&TrianguloIsoseles);

    //Zona de operaciones

    printf("Dame la base %lf \n");

cin>>base;
    printf("Dame la altura %lf \n");

cin>>altura;

    figura1=base*altura/2;

printf("Este esresultado del area de un triangulo escaleno :%lf \n" , figura1);

getchar();

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que tener claro lo primero qué variables vas a utilizar y de qué tipo. Tienes muchas variables que son redundantes y otras que no sirven para nada. Primero, como consejo, antes de programar intenta pensar un poco en lo que quieres conseguir y qué medios te van a hacer falta. Es mejor ir añadiendo variables según codificas y las vas necesitando que declararlas todas al principio.

Por otro lado, un apunte importante. Si estás programando en `C++`, no utilices la función `printf()` o `scanf()`, ya que éstas son de `C`. Has instanciado `using namespace std`, por lo que debes usar `cin` y `cout` como motor de Input/Output con el terminal.

En el siguiente ejemplo que te pongo únicamente he expresado lo que buscas para el triángulo equilátero (todos los lados iguales), ya que para el resto deberás introducir el valor del resto de los lados del triángulo. Por lo que esa tarea te la dejo a ti para que sigas practicando. Mucha suerte y si tienes alguna duda aquí estaremos encantados de ayudarte!

```
//Este programa calcula el área y perímetro

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    printf("En este programas podras calcular el area y perimetro del triangulo escaleno, equilatero\n");

    //Zona de variables

    float base;
    float altura;
    float area;
    float perimetro;


    //Zona de operaciones
    cout << "Dame la base: ";
    cin>>base;

    cout << "Dame la altura: ";
    cin>>altura;

    // Muestra resultados
    cout << "TRIANGULO EQUILATERO" << endl;
    cout << " -- perimetro = " << base*3 << "      -- area = " << (base*altura)/2 << endl;

    return 0;

}
```